# The alert, hasClass and other doesn't work pikachoose slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, removeclass, pikachoose

Here is my website:
http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex/

I exactly added the "pikachoose" gallery slider plugin (it's free - http://www.pikachoose.com), and it works so fine!
You can see the thumbnails under the full image. I finally solved to make captions at the center of the thumbs.

And you can see the `<li class="active capik-no">` thumb active status, and you can see the slider continuously changing the images after a few seconds.. When the slider changes to another image, the first current `<li class="active capik-no">` changing to simple `<li>` and the second `<li>` changing to `<li class="active capik-no">`. Yea this is an automatic slider everlasting process..

**My problem is:**
I'm tried to do the `alert()` fn. like this:

```
        if ($('.pikachoose li').hasClass("active")) {
           alert('test');
        }
```

or

```
        if ($('.pikachoose li').hasClass("capik-no")) {
           alert('test');
        }
```

The `capik-no` is just a test class. With a `"display: none;"` css code.
The `capik` is just a test class. With a `"display: block; position: absolute;"` css code.

The alert and console.log doesn't work...
and you can see in the code `<span class="capik">Text 1</span>` "capik" class is the thumbnail caption...

**My plan is:**
Trying to change the thumb's active status to this: Active thumb status don't have caption.. Only the passive status thumbs have. And I'd like to solve this with `hasClass, addClass, removeClass` variety of solutions.

BUT.... The alert and others doesn't work... **I guess JQuery generates the `active` and `capik-no` classes...**

So especially the system can't find this `<li>` classes because of generated by JQuery??? The alert can't run.. the console.log can't run with these classes.....

**So the `hasClass` and others can't run too... And I can't solve to make the active thumb status to hide the caption with `capika-no` class....**

Here is the js: http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex/js/jquery.pikachoose.js

Please check the either thumb image element (Ctrl-Shift-i).
Here is the simple code:

```
<div class="pikachoose">
    <ul class="jcarousel-skin-pika pika-thumbs">
        <li class="active capik-no">
            <div class="clip">
                <img ref="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/big/1.jpg" src="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/small/1.jpg" class="" style="display: inline; width: 100%; opacity: 0.4;">
                <span class="capik">Text 1</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="clip">
                <img ref="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/big/2.jpg" src="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/small/2.jpg" class="" style="display: inline; width: 100%; opacity: 0.4;">
                <span class="capik">Text 2</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="clip">
                <img ref="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/big/3.jpg" src="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/small/3.jpg" class="" style="display: inline; width: 100%; opacity: 0.451875827717631;">
                <span class="capik">Text 3</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="clip">
                <img ref="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/big/4.jpg" src="http://www.proservinformatika.hu/!orex//images/slider-main/small/4.jpg" class="active capik-no" style="display: inline; width: 100%; opacity: 1;">
                <span class="capik">Text 4</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My current code to solve the problem is (but doesn't work...=/ ):**

```
if($('.pikachoose li').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.pikachoose li span').addClass('capik-no');
    $('.pikachoose li span').removeClass('capik');
} else {
    $('.pikachoose li span').addClass('capik');
    $('.pikachoose li span').removeClass('capik-no');
}
```

Please heelp!!:/ I want to hide the caption from the activated status of the thumb!!:(

Comment: When do you run the code above? Do you have a hook to `slideChange` or something similar?

Comment: Nope, i guess . btw i ran 5 mins ago.. But trying to use the 'active' or 'capik-no' class.. but when I refreshing the site.. and alert or console.log doesn't work..:/ as though does not find to the classes.. =( I'm trying to do an hasClass, addClass, removeClass to hide the activated status caption by active class... but... nothing happens :/

Comment: ehhh.. thx i didn't try that lol... and I want to do it same as on hover effect, now works, but I'd like to do at hover effect!:) But very thank bro for your help ehh. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide the caption from the activated status of the thumb

I think all you need here is a bit of CSS to hide the caption `<span class="capik">` when the `li` has the class `active`

```
.pika-thumbs .active .capik { display: none; }
```

Hide caption when the thumb is hovered on:

```
.pika-thumbs li:hover .capik { display: none; }
```

Comment: I want to give you a +1, and +1 +1 :) Thx for the helpful answer bro btw! I rlly dont know why i didn't think about the css lol

Comment: I can't right now, got only 11 repu :/ but i do not forget you.. :)